# padding in the `a` element goes out of table cell instead of fetch the height

Tags: html, css

In my table, i have a `a` element. I am applying the `padding` on that. But the padding goes out of the `cell` instead of `fetch` the height of the `table-cell` - what is wrong here?

here is the snippet :

```css
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    clear : both;
    border-top:1px solid gray;
}

.column {
    display:table-cell;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    height:2em;
    border-right:1px solid gray;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.table2 a {
    clear:both;
    padding-top:2em;
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="column">Another Table</div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div class="table table2">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="#">Testing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the display of the anchor to `block` or `inline-block`

```css
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    clear : both;
    border-top:1px solid gray;
}

.column {
    display:table-cell;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    height:2em;
    border-right:1px solid gray;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.table2 a {
    clear:both;
    display:block; /*<--- Here*/
    padding-top:2em;
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="column">Another Table</div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div class="table table2">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="#">Testing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow:hidden` to `.column` class in CSS. That should solve your problem.

```css
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    clear : both;
    border-top:1px solid gray;
}

.column {
    display:table-cell;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    height:2em;
    border-right:1px solid gray;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    overflow:hidden; /* This is added */
}

.table2 a {
    clear:both;
    padding-top:2em;
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="column">Another Table</div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div class="table table2">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="#">Testing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```